# Overleaf automatically update png figures

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am working on an overleaf project with involves several figures which are all in .png format. I know how to upload figures into overleaf and how to include them in the text.

However, I have to modify and adjust these plots quite often and it seems cumbersome to upload the new plot everytime. What I am looking for is a way to automize this process in a way that I have a folder on my drive in which I save all the figures. Overleaf would then automatically get the figures from this folder and update them.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: if you have premium account: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization

Comment: for something free https://github.com/moritzgloeckl/overleaf-sync